# How to get a compiler error when expected type changes

Tags: c++, qt, c++11

I have some code in my app which in simplified form goes:

```
QVariantMap deviceMap;
deviceMap.insert("Model", pDevice->Type());
QJsonDocument jsonDoc = QJsonDocument::fromVariant(deviceMap);
QString str = jsonDoc.toJson(QJsonDocument::Compact);
```

I've just found a bug where someone changed the function `Type()` from:

```
QString Type() const;
```

to:

```
int Type() const;
```

Obviously Qt was fine with this and just converted it to JSON which caused the bug. But I'd rather get a compiler error when a type is changed like this. How can I change this so I get a compiler error if the return of a function changes in future?

Comment: You want a check on the type of `pDevice->Type()` specifically, or function changes in general?

Comment: As long as it is valid C++ the compiler will happily compile it.  What you need are [Unit Tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest workaround would be to include a `static_assert` for the returned value of `Type()` in the code.  But of course, you do not want to do that everywhere.

```
static_assert( std::is_same<decltype(pDevice->Type()), QString>::value,
               "Type mismatch, expected QString" );
deviceMap.insert("Model", pDevice->Type());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use free-standing functions:

```
void insertModel(QVariantMap& deviceMap, const QString& str)
{
    deviceMap.insert("Model", str);
}
insertModel(deviceMap, pDevice->Type());
```

or more generic:

```
void insertString(QVariantMap& deviceMap, const char* key, const QString& str)
{
    deviceMap.insert(key, str);
}
insertString(deviceMap, "Model", pDevice->Type());
```

In both cases code will work as long as `Type()` returns QString or anything that can be converted to a QString. You may also static_assert that Type() returns QString.